# Postgresql перед записью проверить на наличие дубликата и вернуть id

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо перед вставкой проверять на наличие записи, если нет добавить, если есть получить id

Нашел такой пример

`INSERT INTO modules (name) SELECT 'Module_name' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modules WHERE name='Module_name' LIMIT 1) RETURNING id;`

но он возвращает id, только при добавлении, если запись существует он не возвращает id

Comment: Лучше сразу используйте `ON CONFLICT`

Comment: `ON CONFLICT` - не совсем подходит, там нужно использовать `update` что увеличивает индекс id на +1

Comment: Ваш комментарий говорит либо о том, что Вы неверно или неполно описываете задачу, либо о том, что Вы просто не разобрались в использовании ON CONFLICT.